# Redirecting a user to external site from XML response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to get a php file, the php file makes a php curl request to an external site with information for a payment request, the external site returns XML which looks like this:

```
<Request valid="1">
<URI>www.dynamicpaymentpage.com/URI>
</Request>
```

After making the request I want to find the URI and redirect the customer to that URI with Jquery. I'm able to find the URI and return it in text or as an alert, but can't work out how to redirect the page.  To be honest, I am pretty inexperienced with Jquery and PHP and am not sure where to go from here. I've basically tried window.location and haven't been able to get that working and I'm not sure where to go from here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
type: "GET",      
url: "deets.php", 
success: function(result){
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $URI = $xml.find( "URI" );
///this is just to make sure I've found the right bit of XML /// $( "#div1" ).append( $URI.text() );

        }});
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>

<button>Go!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would resort to a normal anchor tag for this, and do the redirect with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to assign the URL to `window.location` like:

```
window.location.href = $xml.find("URI").text();
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your button click function.

```
window.location.href = "your-url";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could try something like this

```
<page view-id="/view.xhtml">
  <action execute="#{facesContext.externalContext.redirect('http://')}" />
</page>
```